# Send longer parameters in HTTP GET request

Tags: rest, post, get, restful-architecture

I am trying to call an GET API where I need to pass lat,lon values

https://domainname.com/path?lat=39.0&lon=99.0&lat=23.50209&lon=78.85565&.... 1000 times

It works fine upto 300 repetation but after that it gives error saying ***"400 Bad Request"***

I can change the API to POST method but it violates the REST API resource concept as we are getting information of lat and lon. So it should be GET.

Any suggestion on how to solve this? Shall I change it to POST or any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a good practice to keep URLs shorter than 2,000 characters.

So, my first question would be: Is it really necessary to handle more than 300 repetitions of those parameters? Is there a way you can split the service/params?

If that's not possible (or doesn't make sense), probably using a `POST` works for you. Don't be afraid of violating rules, but do not violate them without a good reason.

Comment: Each lat,lon,height makes a group for one request. I need to send reqeust for 500 location, meaning 500 lat, 500 lon and 500 height. I cannot split this to service params.